# Disable jqgrid drag and drop dinamically

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using drag and drop between rows on jqgrid and i want to disable and enable it dinamically.

```
jQuery("#grid1").jqGrid('gridDnD',{connectWith:'#grid2,#grid3'});
```

How can i archieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `.draggable("disable")` method (see [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#method-disable)) on every row of the grid `grid1` to prevent dragging of rows:

```
$("#grid1").children("tbody")
    .children("tr.jqgrow")
    .draggable("disable");
```

See the demo https://jsfiddle.net/zocdqtj7/37/